# Plot 2 y axis with different scales

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want ggplot2 graph with 2 y axis with different scales. I tried with `sec_axis( )` but finding difficulty to scale it.

**My code**

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mydf)  +
  geom_line(aes(x=Month, y=SalesRate),stat="identity", color = "red") +
  geom_bar(aes(x=Month,  y=Sales),stat="identity", fill = "blue") +
  scale_y_continuous("SalesRate",
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~ ., name="Sales")
  )
```

**Desired Graph**
[image: graph]

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way

```
mydf %>%
  mutate(Month = ym(Month)) %>%
  ggplot() +
  
  geom_bar(aes(x=Month,  y=Sales ),stat="identity", fill = "steelblue") +
  geom_line(aes(x=Month, y=SalesRate  * 24796.84),stat="identity", color = "greenyellow", lwd = 2) +
  scale_y_continuous("SalesRate",
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~ ./24796.84, name="Sales")
  )
```

[image]

If you want percentage,

```
mydf %>%
  mutate(Month = as.POSIXct(ym(Month))) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  
  geom_bar(aes(x=(Month),  y=Sales ),stat="identity", fill = "steelblue") +
  geom_line(aes(x=(Month), y=SalesRate  * 24796.84),stat="identity", color = "greenyellow", lwd = 2) +
  scale_y_continuous("SalesRate",
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~ (./24796.84)* 100, name="Sales")
  ) +
  scale_x_datetime(labels = date_format("%Y%m"), breaks = date_breaks("months"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Much appreciated. Seems sales and sales rate are swapped in your solution. I need sales rate on primary y axis which is in percentage. X axis should be in the same format as raw data. what is 24796.84? Scale should be dynamic as per data. Thanks once again!

Comment: @john I'm sorry that I change order of line and bar because I cannot find how to make line locate front of bar chart. I'll find a way to format date same as raw data.   24796.84 is `max(SalesRate)/max(Sales)`

Comment: Sure, thanks. Do you mean `max(mydf$Sales)/max(mydf$SalesRate)`

Comment: @john Yeap. That's right.

Comment: @john I edit x axis.

Comment: Thank you. Would it be possible to have just month, not (month)?

Comment: @john I forgot to remove ()...